# stdout buffering even after fflush

Tags: c, stream, buffer, stdout, fflush

I've written a simple C program that is meant to pipe `stdin` to `stdout` without buffering characters:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int c;

  while ((c = getchar()) != -1) {
    putchar(c);
    fflush(stdout);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

However, this program still seems to be buffering characters until newlines, despite the call to `fflush`. Why is this happening and how can I fix it (if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the buffering is done by the terminal driver which doesn't send the input to your program until you press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. So your program doesn't even get any characters and `fflush()` isn't even called. It's just waiting for input at the `getchar()` call.